# Passing values from Activty to Adapter(Working fine but sometimes app not responding)

Tags: android

I am sending the values from Activity to the Adapter and it's working. but sometimes it's run perfectly but sometimes it gives not responding error in the emulator. don't know why it happening

I am showing the images grid view which is fetched from MYSQL server.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String URL_LOGIN= "http://10.0.2.2/e-stitch/fatchimg.php?apicall=shirt";
    public static String[] mThumbIds;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter (MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userLogin();
        final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                //i.putExtra("id", position);
                //startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void userLogin() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                            if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                JSONArray arrJson = obj.getJSONArray("user");
                                mThumbIds = new String[arrJson.length()];
                                for(int i = 0; i < arrJson.length(); i++) {
                                    mThumbIds[i] = arrJson.getString(i);
                                }
                                imageAdapter.setimag(mThumbIds);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("shirt", "shirt");
                return params;
            }

        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    int imageTotal=6;

    public static String[] mThumbIds;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void setimag(String[] mThumbIds){
        this.mThumbIds = mThumbIds;
        this.imageTotal = 6;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageTotal;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(480, 480));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        String url = getItem(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loader)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop().into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about VolleSingleton, but could this line "VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);" be executing a long running network task on the UI thread? If so, that is whats causing the app to become non-responsive. Since network conditions vary, and even repeating the same network requests can have different execution times, you should always perform an I/O and networking work on a background thread.

Comment: I should consider this